# How to getting hostname from urlbar using gupsup ide?

Tags: javascript, angular, gupshup

I try to getting hostname from my website url but when i make javascript code var hostname = location.hostname then default screen code doesn't execute. How to get hostname from web url.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "default screen code"? `location.hostname` is the correct JS code to get what you are looking for.

Comment: In Gupshup IDE more files available like default.scr and index.js. when i put location.hostname in index.js then default.scr code is not executed, it's given error in chatbot and my requirement is getting weburl which page stand by user.

Comment: location.hostname will not work in your chatbot project files. Is your Gupshup bot published on Web widget? if yes, let me know I will share a sample script which will help to fetch hostname on which the widget is working.